# Laravel 9 Rest API - pagination meta tag unavaible when return it with response()

Tags: laravel, rest

**Controllers/Komic Controller**

```
public function search($value)
   {
       // Query Wildcards and Resources
       $result = new KomikCollection(Komik::where('judul', 'like', '%'. $value .'%')->paginate(2));
       return $result;
   }
```

its fine when i directly return the $result

```
{
"data": [],
"links": {
"first": "http://localhost:8000/api/komik/a?page=1",
"last": "http://localhost:8000/api/komik/a?page=2",
"prev": null,
"next": "http://localhost:8000/api/komik/a?page=2"
},
"meta": {
"current_page": 1,
"from": 1,
"last_page": 2,
"links": [
{
"url": null,
"label": "&laquo; Previous",
"active": false
},
{
"url": "http://localhost:8000/api/komik/a?page=1",
"label": "1",
"active": true
},
{
"url": "http://localhost:8000/api/komik/a?page=2",
"label": "2",
"active": false
},
{
"url": "http://localhost:8000/api/komik/a?page=2",
"label": "Next &raquo;",
"active": false
}
],
"path": "http://localhost:8000/api/komik/a",
"per_page": 2,
"to": 2,
"total": 4
}
}
```

but when i'll return it using **helpers/response**

```
    public function search($value)
    {
        // Query Wildcards and Resources
        $result = new KomikCollection(Komik::where('judul', 'like', '%'. $value .'%')->paginate(2));

        // send response
        return response()->json($result, 200);
    }
```

the meta and link on the json response will be disapppear and return result like this

```
{
"id": 1,
"title": "Spare me, Great Lord !"
},
{
"id": 2,
"title": "I'm An Evil God"
}
```

I want the response include the meta and link tags, how do i fix this?

Comment: Please attach a resource collection file code so that we can identify whether the resource code is for a single resource or multiple resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to meta data with response then you must need to add `->response()->getData(true)` in collection results.

So your final function looks like :

```
public function search($value)
{
    // Query Wildcards and Resources
    $result = new KomikCollection(Komik::where('judul', 'like', '%'. $value .'%')->paginate(2))->response()->getData(true);

    // send response
    return response()->json($result, 200);
}
```

Comment: i get syntax error from this

Comment: send me a error here so that I will give you a solution for that

Comment: oh my bad the wrong at me

Answer (score 0):

As your code is written here, there's no need to use the helper function because when the resource is returned, it is sent with a `200 OK` status.

However, I've seen this exact thing done on projects I've worked on. If you are trying to use the helper to avoid the returned data being double wrapped, the best practice to modify this behavior is [documented here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-resources#data-wrapping).